# Let $a$,$b$,$c > 0$ satisfy $abc = 1$ . Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2}}}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a$, $b$, $c > 0$ satisfy $abc = 1$ . Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{2}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{2}}} \ge \sqrt{2}$ .

$a$, $b$, $c > 0$ and $abc = 1$

Let $a = \frac{x}{y}$, $b = \frac{y}{z}$, $c = \frac{z}{x}$; $x$,$y$,$z > 0$

What should be the next step after reforming the inequality in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$?

*My apology for not putting further steps since it's way too tedious to write everything in latex and especially nested reciprocal of radicals.*

Comment: @Ash_Blanc : If the answer in the linked question is not satisfactory then try an Approach Zero search. There are many threads about this inequality literally everywhere on MSE AND AoPS.

Comment: I revise my previous comment. Here we have real numbers with product equal to one. In the older question the assumption is that $a,b,c$ are integers (and adding the condition $abc=1$ would make that problem trivial). Also I find the solution to the older question incomplete, therefore I would not choose that as a duplicate target. – Here is another one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577453/42969 but that looks a bit too complicated?

Comment: @MartinR yeah that's way too complicated

Comment: Actually https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445051/42969 is wrong: The inequality does not hold for arbitrary positive integers.

Comment: @MartinR but how ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc: The proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445103/42969 seems to be correct if you assume that $a, b, c$ are real numbers with $abc=1$. It solves *this* problem but not the one for which is was posted (where $a, b, c$ are integers with arbitrary product).